# How to get value from input onclick with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, get, onclick, row

How I can get value from row that I click?

Here's a little example:

```
<div class="row" id="multiRows">
    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"><input id="DescRepair_0" name="dynfields[0][DescRepair]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"><input id="NestParts_0" name="dynfields[0][NestParts]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 removeDiv"><input id="EdPrice_0" name="dynfields[0][EdPrice]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 removeDiv"><input id="DateRepair_0" name="dynfields[0][DateRepair]" class="form-control dateBox removeDiv" type="text"></div>
        <input id="repairID_0" name="dynfields[0][repairID]" value="1" class="form-control removeDiv" type="hidden">
        <img class="removeRow removeImg removeDiv" src="img/remove.png" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"><input id="DescRepair_1" name="dynfields[1][DescRepair]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"><input id="NestParts_1" name="dynfields[1][NestParts]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 removeDiv"><input id="EdPrice_1" name="dynfields[1][EdPrice]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 removeDiv"><input id="DateRepair_1" name="dynfields[1][DateRepair]" class="form-control dateBox removeDiv" type="text"></div>
        <input id="repairID_1" name="dynfields[1][repairID]" value="2" class="form-control removeDiv" type="hidden">
        <img class="removeRow removeImg removeDiv" src="img/remove.png" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the img, I want to get the value of hidden input (id="repairID_X). I tried several options, but I could not do what I want, I will be happy if someone help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have two child divs in each row each with it's input element `repairID_` then you want to attach the event listener to the child divs or the images:

```
$('.row > div').on('click', function() {
    var val = $('input[id^="repairID_"]', this).val();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7wh7kL1L/1/)

Or using the image:

```
$('.row img.removeRow').on('click', function() {
    var val = $(this).prev().val();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/7wh7kL1L/2/)

If you just want the values of the two hidden inputs irrespective of what image was clicked use this:

```
$('img.removeRow').on('click', function() {
    var values = $(this).closest('.row').find(':hidden[id^="repairID_"]').map(function(i,v) {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(','); //result: "1,2"
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/7wh7kL1L/3/)

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is the value, the hidden input is redundant. Why not use [data-*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attributes with HTML5?

```
<img class="removeRow removeImg removeDiv" src="img/remove.png" width="100%" data-repair="2">
```

Then you can bind the click event directly to the image.

```
$('img.removeRow').click(function () {
    var value = $(this).data('repair');
    // use value
});
```

This way you can pass along as much info as you want through data tags.

Answer (score 2):

You need some way to link the image with the input. This is how I'd do it :

Add a class to your img so it's easier to select with jquery (like "clickable" or something), and a data attribute referencing the input id so it'll look like that :

```
<input id="repairID_X" […] type="hidden">
<img class="removeRow removeImg removeDiv clickable" data-input-id="repairID_X" […] >
```

Then, in your javascript :

```
$('.clickable').click(function() {
    var input_id = $(this).data('input-id');
    var input_value = $('#' + input_id).val();
});
```

The advantage is that it will work even if you change the disposition of the elements in the DOM because the images are tied to the inputs via the data attribute.

Edit : pokkanome's solution is smarter.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and the contains(*) selector

```
$('.row > div').click(function() {
      var theValue = $(this).find('[id*="repairID_"]').val();
    });
```

```js
$('.row > div').click(function() {
  var theValue = $(this).find('[id*="repairID_"]').val();
  console.log(theValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="multiRows">
  <div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input id="DescRepair_0" name="dynfields[0][DescRepair]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input id="NestParts_0" name="dynfields[0][NestParts]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 removeDiv">
      <input id="EdPrice_0" name="dynfields[0][EdPrice]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 removeDiv">
      <input id="DateRepair_0" name="dynfields[0][DateRepair]" class="form-control dateBox removeDiv" type="text">
    </div>
    <input id="repairID_0" name="dynfields[0][repairID]" value="1" class="form-control removeDiv" type="hidden">
    <img class="removeRow removeImg removeDiv" src="img/remove.png" width="100%">
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input id="DescRepair_1" name="dynfields[1][DescRepair]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input id="NestParts_1" name="dynfields[1][NestParts]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 removeDiv">
      <input id="EdPrice_1" name="dynfields[1][EdPrice]" class="form-control removeDiv" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 removeDiv">
      <input id="DateRepair_1" name="dynfields[1][DateRepair]" class="form-control dateBox removeDiv" type="text">
    </div>
    <input id="repairID_1" name="dynfields[1][repairID]" value="2" class="form-control removeDiv" type="hidden">
    <img class="removeRow removeImg removeDiv" src="img/remove.png" width="100%">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it works, but if I click on another row will return 2 again.

Comment: @diank, perhaps I am misunderstading. Dont you want to get the hidden filed with an id that contains repairID?

Comment: Almost works, the problem is that when click on row one displays the value of row 2.

Comment: @diank, check the code snippet in my updated answer. It is working there